# Outlook 2010 Exchange server requiring different login credentials

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

I'm trying to add a new installation of Outlook 2010 to an Exchange server. The server appears to connect but requires an additional username/password and it accepts nothing, whether you input the correct email (user) and password, the local admin, or a local user.

I have reinstalled the application and cleaned its registry listing as well as removed all traces in the temp folder.

Has anyone ever encountered this?

Comment: Can the affected user login via OWA (Outlook Web Access)?

Answer (score 0):

So this was resolved by downloading an update that didn't pull automatically via Windows update.  The update in question was a Microsoft Exchange Update for Outlook 2010.  I found it via the Office Configuration Analyzer Tool which scanned office software and specified missing updates.